# C programing, For Loop to get each number without using Array

Tags: c

To write a function to get ages from one user, (user's typing is shown in BOLD)
Here is a sample

How many people: **3**

Enter age of person 1: **12**

Enter age of person 2: **10**

Enter age of person 3: **15**

There are 3 People and ages are: 12, 10, and 15

I am confused how to not use array for this kind of question!!! PLZ HELP!!!

Comment: use recursion without array

Comment: Are you allowed to concatenate strings?

Comment: @BillLynch - true.  Then what, bare pointer and malloc?

Comment: I hope age values will not be more than 2 - digits. Then simply as user enters a value, append to an long value, by doing somethingy like `result = ( result * 100 ) + newUserValue`, and when user is done, `mod` the result to get respective values

Comment: There are two ways to do this with for loop. Can you use malloc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lashane suggested:

> Use recursion without array.

It is a fantastic idea. Here's how you could go about it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_rec(int index, int maxindex)
{
    int age;
    printf("Enter age of person %d",index);
    scanf("%d",&age);
    if (index == maxindex)
    {
        printf("The ages are %d ",age);
        return;
    }
    print_rec(index + 1, maxindex);
    printf(",%d",age);
}
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of people : ");
    int num;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    print_rec(1,num);
    return 0;
}
```

The only shortcoming, though is it prints the age in **reverse order**.

Comment: He is asking C not C++

Comment: I'm really sorry. I'll change my answer.

Comment: Yes, i am asking for C programing!! thanks for all comments!!

Comment: The code works!  And I learned from it!  However, the user needs to type how many people first!  then enter each person's age.  How would u do that then!!  thanks

Comment: @Smithdentem edited. If the code works, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark button to turn it green!

Comment: Umm, no. Actually in recursion also we define multiple variables, but it seems *not-too-obvious* as you can see only one statement `int age`. But at every level of recursion, you define a new `int age` at some other location of the memory. `for` loop cannot emulate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store them you can use following, this is embedded way of doing things. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  long ages = 0;
  int cnt = 0, i = 0, age = 0;

  printf("How many people do you have? (8 maximumimum):\t");
  scanf("%d", &cnt);

  for(i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
    printf("Enter the age of person: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    ages = ages | age;
    ages <<= 8;
  }

  ages >>= 8;
  for(; i;  --i) {
    printf("Age of person nubmer %d is %d\n", i, ages & 255);
    ages >>= 8;
  }
}
```

This might not help you but is a cool way of doing it :)